# Get the list of changed directories in last commit

Tags: bash, git, shell, gitlab

I have a requirement where I want to get the list of directories those changed in a last commit. For example that I have a version of a code in my repo, branch name is master. This code has 3 directories and each of them have one file.

```
dir1/file1
dir2/file2
dir3/file3
```

Some other developer worked on this master branch and made some changes. Change are only the content of file2 and file3. This change where made in a single commit. I pull this updated code in my local. What I want is list the directories whose content changed. Output should look like this..

```
dir2
dir3
```

Comment: Not sure why this is duplicated. I know we can use to dirstat to get the change list and extract path from it. I don't want that. Given I didn't do any local change... I want the directories which were changed in last commit by any user.

Answer (score 1):

I don't there's a way to this in git alone, but you can use the `--name-only` option to get a list of changed file names (and an empty format to get just them), and then [`dirname`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname) to extract the directory name from the file. Since a commit can contain changes to several files in the same directory, you'd also want to `uniq` them:

```
$ git show --format="" --name-only | xargs dirname | sort | uniq
```

Comment: This helped. Was able to build solution on top of this with some limitations. `git diff HEAD~1 --name-only `  with this was able to get changed files. After that used `uniq` and `cut -d/ f2 ` specific to my use case. This has limitation of last commit. If I keep from and to commit then I can list all changes someone else did. this certainly helped.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use find to list files that were created or modified more recently than a specified file:

```
find . -newer dir1/file1 -print
```

run from the directory that contains dir1 dir2 and dir3, should list all files from the current directory and lower, that were modified more recently than "dir1/file1" (I'm assuming that your file is older than the files that were recently pulled). It will then print the list to the standard output.

```
man find
```

shows other options, including anewer and cnewer (access time and status change time newer than a file), as well as -amin -atime -cmin -ctime -mmin and -mtime. These might be worth looking at in your situation :-)